# Gnuplot: How to plot a task scheduling graphic

Tags: plot, scheduled-tasks, gnuplot

I'm a completely newbie with Gnuplot, I just read this basic tutorial: [http://people.duke.edu/~hpgavin/gnuplot.html](http://people.duke.edu/%7Ehpgavin/gnuplot.html)

I want to plot this data:

```
Processor1 t4 2 7 t3 7 12 t2 12 17
Processor2 t5 0 9 t1 10 13
```

And the resulting plot should be something like this image:

[image]

I searched through the web but I didn't find any plot like this, the most similar that I found were stacked bars, but they are not what I need.

Someone knows how to get close to this plot using Gnuplot (could be other plotting program, I choose Gnuplot because it's a well known tool for this purpose).

@edit 1

The image above is from http://rtime.felk.cvut.cz/scheduling-toolbox/manual/algorithms-scheduling.php

@edit 2

I'd like to thank Michael O. for generate a plotting for my data, even being a manual plotting it was amazing.

Actually I gave up of trying to plot this using a generic plotting program, like gnuplot. I started using the matlab toolbox that generated the image above: rtime.felk.cvut.cz/scheduling-toolbox

It was fairly simple to plot this using this toolbox, I'm going to write here the script I used to plot the graphic referring to the data above.

Script: schedulingSample.m

```
addpath(path,'/home/carloshmm/Matlab/toolbox/TORSCHE/scheduling/');
t1 = task('t1', 3, 10, inf, inf, 1, 2);
t2 = task('t2', 5, 12, inf, inf, 1, 1);
t3 = task('t3', 5, 7, inf, inf, 1, 1);
t4 = task('t4', 5, 2, inf, inf, 1, 1);
t5 = task('t5', 9, 0, inf, inf, 1, 2);
T = [t1 t2 t3 t4 t5];
add_schedule(T, 'Task Scheduling Graphic', T.ReleaseTime, T.ProcTime, T.Processor);
plot(T);
waitforbuttonpress;
```

Resulting plot:

[image]

Comment: Actually I gave up of trying to plot this using a generic plotting program, like gnuplot. I started using the matlab toolbox that generated the image above: rtime.felk.cvut.cz/scheduling-toolbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here is my attempt to plot your graph "manually", i.e. without reading your data with gnuplot directly, because, as I think, it's impossible to do so. If you want to automate plotting, I suggest to create gnuplot script from some external program, where you can calculate all positions and plot parameters.

```
set term pngcairo dashed size 800,400
set output 'boxes.png'
set style fill solid
unset ytics
set ytics('Processor1' 1.5,'Processor2' 0.5)
unset key
set xrange [-1:20]
set yrange [0:2]
set xlabel 't'
set object 1 rectangle from 2,1 to 7,1.7 fc rgb 'gold'
set object 2 rectangle from 7,1 to 12,1.7 fc rgb 'light-green'
set object 3 rectangle from 12,1 to 17,1.7 fc rgb 'light-blue'
set object 4 rectangle from 0,0 to 9,0.7 fc rgb 'red'
set object 5 rectangle from 10,0 to 13,0.7 fc rgb 'blue'
set arrow 1 from 2,1 to 2,1.85 filled fc rgb 'gold'
set arrow 2 from 7,1 to 7,1.85 filled fc rgb 'light-green'
set arrow 3 from 12,1 to 12,1.85 filled fc rgb 'light-blue'
set arrow 4 from 0,0 to 0,0.85 filled fc rgb 'red'
set arrow 5 from 10,0 to 10,0.85 filled fc rgb 'blue'
set label 1 't4' at 2,1.05
set label 2 't3' at 7,1.05
set label 3 't2' at 12,1.05
set label 4 't5' at 0,0.05
set label 5 't1' at 10,0.05
plot 1 w l lt 2 lc rgb 'red'
```

[image]